# Swift 2 Object Mapper class append doesn't work, result nil

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2, objectmapper

I'm using Object Mapper in Swift 2 (when I download from api it worked well) but I want to add some objects inside my class with append. It currently doesn't work, i.e. it doesnt add any object.

My codes are below:

**myHomesClass.swift**

```
import Foundation

class MyHomes : NSObject,Mappable {

    var first                   : String?;
    var second                  : String?;
    var number1                 : String?;
    var selected                : String?;


    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {
        self.init()
     mapping(map)
    }



    func mapping(_ map: Map) {

        first           <- map["first"]
        second          <- map["second"]
        number1         <- map["number1"]

    }
}
```

My ViewController.Swift

```
    import UIKit
    import Foundation

    class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var homes                      : [MyHomes]?
    var selectedHomes              : [MyHomes]?


            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()

                 if homes != nil {
                    for datasinhomes in homes! {
                        if datasinhomes.selected == "yes" {
                           print("selected yes have")
                           self.selectedHomes?.append(datasinhomes)
                            }
 }
}

                 print("selectedHomesCount=\(self.selectedHomes.count)")

}

    }
```

**Result**

```
selected yes have
selected yes have
selected yes have
selectedHomesCount=nil
```

**Mappable.swift**

```
//
//  Mappable.swift
//  ObjectMapper
//
//  Created by Scott Hoyt on 10/25/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 hearst. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation

public protocol Mappable {
    init?(_ map: Map)
    mutating func mapping(map: Map)
}

public protocol MappableCluster: Mappable {
    static func objectForMapping(map: Map) -> Mappable?
}

public extension Mappable {

    /// Initializes object from a JSON String
    public init?(JSONString: String) {
        if let obj: Self = Mapper().map(JSONString) {
            self = obj
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    /// Initializes object from a JSON Dictionary
    public init?(JSON: [String : AnyObject]) {
        if let obj: Self = Mapper().map(JSON) {
            self = obj
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    /// Returns the JSON Dictionary for the object
    public func toJSON() -> [String: AnyObject] {
        return Mapper().toJSON(self)
    }

    /// Returns the JSON String for the object
    public func toJSONString(prettyPrint: Bool = false) -> String? {
        return Mapper().toJSONString(self, prettyPrint: prettyPrint)
    }
}

public extension Array where Element: Mappable {

    /// Initialize Array from a JSON String
    public init?(JSONString: String) {
        if let obj: [Element] = Mapper().mapArray(JSONString) {
            self = obj
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    /// Initialize Array from a JSON Array
    public init?(JSONArray: [[String : AnyObject]]) {
        if let obj: [Element] = Mapper().mapArray(JSONArray) {
            self = obj
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    /// Returns the JSON Array
    public func toJSON() -> [[String : AnyObject]] {
        return Mapper().toJSONArray(self)
    }

    /// Returns the JSON String for the object
    public func toJSONString(prettyPrint: Bool = false) -> String? {
        return Mapper().toJSONString(self, prettyPrint: prettyPrint)
    }
}

public extension Set where Element: Mappable {

    /// Initializes a set from a JSON String
    public init?(JSONString: String) {
        if let obj: Set<Element> = Mapper().mapSet(JSONString) {
            self = obj
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    /// Initializes a set from JSON
    public init?(JSONArray: [[String : AnyObject]]) {
        if let obj: Set<Element> = Mapper().mapSet(JSONArray) {
            self = obj
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    /// Returns the JSON Set
    public func toJSON() -> [[String : AnyObject]] {
        return Mapper().toJSONSet(self)
    }

    /// Returns the JSON String for the object
    public func toJSONString(prettyPrint: Bool = false) -> String? {
        return Mapper().toJSONString(self, prettyPrint: prettyPrint)
    }
}
```

**Mapper.swift**

```
//
//  Mapper.swift
//  ObjectMapper
//
//  Created by Tristan Himmelman on 2014-10-09.
//
//  The MIT License (MIT)
//
//  Copyright (c) 2014-2015 Hearst
//
//  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
//  of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
//  in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
//  to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
//  copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
//  furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
//
//  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
//  all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
//  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
//  IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
//  FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
//  AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
//  LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
//  OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
//  THE SOFTWARE.

import Foundation

public enum MappingType {
    case FromJSON
    case ToJSON
}

/// The Mapper class provides methods for converting Model objects to JSON and methods for converting JSON to Model objects
public final class Mapper<N: Mappable> {

    public init(){}

    // MARK: Mapping functions that map to an existing object toObject

    /// Maps a JSON object to an existing Mappable object if it is a JSON dictionary, or returns the passed object as is
    public func map(JSON: AnyObject?, toObject object: N) -> N {
        if let JSON = JSON as? [String : AnyObject] {
            return map(JSON, toObject: object)
        }

        return object
    }

    /// Map a JSON string onto an existing object
    public func map(JSONString: String, toObject object: N) -> N {
        if let JSON = Mapper.parseJSONDictionary(JSONString) {
            return map(JSON, toObject: object)
        }
        return object
    }

    /// Maps a JSON dictionary to an existing object that conforms to Mappable.
    /// Usefull for those pesky objects that have crappy designated initializers like NSManagedObject
    public func map(JSONDictionary: [String : AnyObject], var toObject object: N) -> N {
        let map = Map(mappingType: .FromJSON, JSONDictionary: JSONDictionary, toObject: true)
        object.mapping(map)
        return object
    }

    //MARK: Mapping functions that create an object

    /// Map an optional JSON string to an object that conforms to Mappable
    public func map(JSONString: String?) -> N? {
        if let JSONString = JSONString {
            return map(JSONString)
        }

        return nil
    }

    /// Map a JSON string to an object that conforms to Mappable
    public func map(JSONString: String) -> N? {
        if let JSON = Mapper.parseJSONDictionary(JSONString) {
            return map(JSON)
        }

        return nil
    }

    /// Map a JSON NSString to an object that conforms to Mappable
    public func map(JSONString: NSString) -> N? {
        return map(JSONString as String)
    }

    /// Maps a JSON object to a Mappable object if it is a JSON dictionary or NSString, or returns nil.
    public func map(JSON: AnyObject?) -> N? {
        if let JSON = JSON as? [String : AnyObject] {
            return map(JSON)
        }

        return nil
    }

    /// Maps a JSON dictionary to an object that conforms to Mappable
    public func map(JSONDictionary: [String : AnyObject]) -> N? {
        let map = Map(mappingType: .FromJSON, JSONDictionary: JSONDictionary)

        // check if N is of type MappableCluster
        if let klass = N.self as? MappableCluster.Type {
            if var object = klass.objectForMapping(map) as? N {
                object.mapping(map)
                return object
            }
        }

        if var object = N(map) {
            object.mapping(map)
            return object
        }
        return nil
    }

    // MARK: Mapping functions for Arrays and Dictionaries

    /// Maps a JSON array to an object that conforms to Mappable
    public func mapArray(JSONString: String) -> [N]? {
        let parsedJSON: AnyObject? = Mapper.parseJSONString(JSONString)

        if let objectArray = mapArray(parsedJSON) {
            return objectArray
        }

        // failed to parse JSON into array form
        // try to parse it into a dictionary and then wrap it in an array
        if let object = map(parsedJSON) {
            return [object]
        }

        return nil
    }

    /// Maps a optional JSON String into an array of objects that conforms to Mappable
    public func mapArray(JSONString: String?) -> [N]? {
        if let JSONString = JSONString {
            return mapArray(JSONString)
        }

        return nil
    }

    /// Maps a JSON object to an array of Mappable objects if it is an array of JSON dictionary, or returns nil.
    public func mapArray(JSON: AnyObject?) -> [N]? {
        if let JSONArray = JSON as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
            return mapArray(JSONArray)
        }

        return nil
    }

    /// Maps an array of JSON dictionary to an array of Mappable objects
    public func mapArray(JSONArray: [[String : AnyObject]]) -> [N]? {
        // map every element in JSON array to type N
        let result = JSONArray.flatMap(map)
        return result
    }

    /// Maps a JSON object to a dictionary of Mappable objects if it is a JSON dictionary of dictionaries, or returns nil.
    public func mapDictionary(JSONString: String) -> [String : N]? {
        let parsedJSON: AnyObject? = Mapper.parseJSONString(JSONString)
        return mapDictionary(parsedJSON)
    }

    /// Maps a JSON object to a dictionary of Mappable objects if it is a JSON dictionary of dictionaries, or returns nil.
    public func mapDictionary(JSON: AnyObject?) -> [String : N]? {
        if let JSONDictionary = JSON as? [String : [String : AnyObject]] {
            return mapDictionary(JSONDictionary)
        }

        return nil
    }

    /// Maps a JSON dictionary of dictionaries to a dictionary of Mappble objects
    public func mapDictionary(JSONDictionary: [String : [String : AnyObject]]) -> [String : N]? {
        // map every value in dictionary to type N
        let result = JSONDictionary.filterMap(map)
        if result.isEmpty == false {
            return result
        }

        return nil
    }

    /// Maps a JSON object to a dictionary of Mappable objects if it is a JSON dictionary of dictionaries, or returns nil.
    public func mapDictionary(JSON: AnyObject?, toDictionary dictionary: [String : N]) -> [String : N] {
        if let JSONDictionary = JSON as? [String : [String : AnyObject]] {
            return mapDictionary(JSONDictionary, toDictionary: dictionary)
        }

        return dictionary
    }

    /// Maps a JSON dictionary of dictionaries to an existing dictionary of Mappble objects
    public func mapDictionary(JSONDictionary: [String : [String : AnyObject]], var toDictionary dictionary: [String : N]) -> [String : N] {
        for (key, value) in JSONDictionary {
            if let object = dictionary[key] {
                Mapper().map(value, toObject: object)
            } else {
                dictionary[key] = Mapper().map(value)
            }
        }

        return dictionary
    }

    /// Maps a JSON object to a dictionary of arrays of Mappable objects
    public func mapDictionaryOfArrays(JSON: AnyObject?) -> [String : [N]]? {
        if let JSONDictionary = JSON as? [String : [[String : AnyObject]]] {
            return mapDictionaryOfArrays(JSONDictionary)
        }

        return nil
    }

    ///Maps a JSON dictionary of arrays to a dictionary of arrays of Mappable objects
    public func mapDictionaryOfArrays(JSONDictionary: [String : [[String : AnyObject]]]) -> [String : [N]]? {
        // map every value in dictionary to type N
        let result = JSONDictionary.filterMap {
            mapArray($0)
        }

        if result.isEmpty == false {
            return result
        }

        return nil
    }

    /// Maps an 2 dimentional array of JSON dictionaries to a 2 dimentional array of Mappable objects
    public func mapArrayOfArrays(JSON: AnyObject?) -> [[N]]? {
        if let JSONArray = JSON as? [[[String : AnyObject]]] {
            var objectArray = [[N]]()
            for innerJSONArray in JSONArray {
                if let array = mapArray(innerJSONArray){
                    objectArray.append(array)
                }
            }

            if objectArray.isEmpty == false {
                return objectArray
            }
        }

        return nil
    }

    // MARK: Utility functions for converting strings to JSON objects

    /// Convert a JSON String into a Dictionary<String, AnyObject> using NSJSONSerialization
    public static func parseJSONDictionary(JSON: String) -> [String : AnyObject]? {
        let parsedJSON: AnyObject? = Mapper.parseJSONString(JSON)
        return Mapper.parseJSONDictionary(parsedJSON)
    }

    /// Convert a JSON Object into a Dictionary<String, AnyObject> using NSJSONSerialization
    public static func parseJSONDictionary(JSON: AnyObject?) -> [String : AnyObject]? {
        if let JSONDict = JSON as? [String : AnyObject] {
            return JSONDict
        }

        return nil
    }

    /// Convert a JSON String into an Object using NSJSONSerialization
    public static func parseJSONString(JSON: String) -> AnyObject? {
        let data = JSON.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
        if let data = data {
            let parsedJSON: AnyObject?
            do {
                parsedJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
                parsedJSON = nil
            }
            return parsedJSON
        }

        return nil
    }
}

extension Mapper {

    // MARK: Functions that create JSON from objects    

    ///Maps an object that conforms to Mappable to a JSON dictionary <String : AnyObject>
    public func toJSON(var object: N) -> [String : AnyObject] {
        let map = Map(mappingType: .ToJSON, JSONDictionary: [:])
        object.mapping(map)
        return map.JSONDictionary
    }

    ///Maps an array of Objects to an array of JSON dictionaries [[String : AnyObject]]
    public func toJSONArray(array: [N]) -> [[String : AnyObject]] {
        return array.map {
            // convert every element in array to JSON dictionary equivalent
            self.toJSON($0)
        }
    }

    ///Maps a dictionary of Objects that conform to Mappable to a JSON dictionary of dictionaries.
    public func toJSONDictionary(dictionary: [String : N]) -> [String : [String : AnyObject]] {
        return dictionary.map { k, v in
            // convert every value in dictionary to its JSON dictionary equivalent
            return (k, self.toJSON(v))
        }
    }

    ///Maps a dictionary of Objects that conform to Mappable to a JSON dictionary of dictionaries.
    public func toJSONDictionaryOfArrays(dictionary: [String : [N]]) -> [String : [[String : AnyObject]]] {
        return dictionary.map { k, v in
            // convert every value (array) in dictionary to its JSON dictionary equivalent
            return (k, self.toJSONArray(v))
        }
    }

    /// Maps an Object to a JSON string with option of pretty formatting
    public func toJSONString(object: N, prettyPrint: Bool = false) -> String? {
        let JSONDict = toJSON(object)

        return Mapper.toJSONString(JSONDict, prettyPrint: prettyPrint)
    }

    /// Maps an array of Objects to a JSON string with option of pretty formatting  
    public func toJSONString(array: [N], prettyPrint: Bool = false) -> String? {
        let JSONDict = toJSONArray(array)

        return Mapper.toJSONString(JSONDict, prettyPrint: prettyPrint)
    }

    public static func toJSONString(JSONObject: AnyObject, prettyPrint: Bool) -> String? {
        if NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(JSONObject) {
            let JSONData: NSData?
            do {
                let options: NSJSONWritingOptions = prettyPrint ? .PrettyPrinted : []
                JSONData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(JSONObject, options: options)
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
                JSONData = nil
            }

            if let JSON = JSONData {
                return String(data: JSON, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

extension Mapper where N: Hashable {

    /// Maps a JSON array to an object that conforms to Mappable
    public func mapSet(JSONString: String) -> Set<N>? {
        let parsedJSON: AnyObject? = Mapper.parseJSONString(JSONString)

        if let objectArray = mapArray(parsedJSON){
            return Set(objectArray)
        }

        // failed to parse JSON into array form
        // try to parse it into a dictionary and then wrap it in an array
        if let object = map(parsedJSON) {
            return Set([object])
        }

        return nil
    }

    /// Maps a JSON object to an Set of Mappable objects if it is an array of JSON dictionary, or returns nil.
    public func mapSet(JSON: AnyObject?) -> Set<N>? {
        if let JSONArray = JSON as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
            return mapSet(JSONArray)
        }

        return nil
    }

    /// Maps an Set of JSON dictionary to an array of Mappable objects
    public func mapSet(JSONArray: [[String : AnyObject]]) -> Set<N> {
        // map every element in JSON array to type N
        return Set(JSONArray.flatMap(map))
    }

    ///Maps a Set of Objects to a Set of JSON dictionaries [[String : AnyObject]]
    public func toJSONSet(set: Set<N>) -> [[String : AnyObject]] {
        return set.map {
            // convert every element in set to JSON dictionary equivalent
            self.toJSON($0)
        }
    }

    /// Maps a set of Objects to a JSON string with option of pretty formatting
    public func toJSONString(set: Set<N>, prettyPrint: Bool = false) -> String? {
        let JSONDict = toJSONSet(set)

        return Mapper.toJSONString(JSONDict, prettyPrint: prettyPrint)
    }
}

extension Dictionary {
    internal func map<K: Hashable, V>(@noescape f: Element -> (K, V)) -> [K : V] {
        var mapped = [K : V]()

        for element in self {
            let newElement = f(element)
            mapped[newElement.0] = newElement.1
        }

        return mapped
    }

    internal func map<K: Hashable, V>(@noescape f: Element -> (K, [V])) -> [K : [V]] {
        var mapped = [K : [V]]()

        for element in self {
            let newElement = f(element)
            mapped[newElement.0] = newElement.1
        }

        return mapped
    }


    internal func filterMap<U>(@noescape f: Value -> U?) -> [Key : U] {
        var mapped = [Key : U]()

        for (key, value) in self {
            if let newValue = f(value){
                mapped[key] = newValue
            }
        }

        return mapped
    }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you are not using JSONDecoder() ? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder

Comment: @ekscrypto for json decode dont problem , i got from elements inside homes  from api , problem is i dont add any object inside selectedHomes

Comment: @ekscrypto The OP uses *Stone-Age-Swift* and doesn't want to upgrade 

Comment: @vadian bro ? what do you think ? i think you fix this easily

Comment: I forget (about) Swift 2 completely, sorry

Comment: Are you aware that Swift 2 is long dead? If you intend to submit an app to the App Store then you must use Xcode 9 or later which means you must use Swift 4 or later. Spending time using Swift 2 these days is largely a waste of time. A lot has changed.

Comment: This question has received an answer, but it does not feature a [mcve], and so may not be useful to future readers. It may be better to put this on hold, unless the large amount of code can be trimmed down to an example that is easier to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined:

```
var selectedHomes              : [MyHomes]?
```

Then you try to:

```
self.selectedHomes?.append(datasinhomes)
```

But I do not see anywhere that you actually assigned an array to the selectedHomes so that its value is actually defined.  Attempting to append to nil will obviously not do anything.

Try to change your definition to:

```
var selectedHomes : [MyHomes]? = []
```

If you want to keep this as an optional array or you could at this point make it a non-optional too:

```
var selectedHomes : [MyHomes] = []
```

Good Luck!

Comment: testing.. now dude

Comment: Glad I could be of help.  Cheers!

Comment: bro if i want to add only  1 manual object, will be var selectedHomes : MyHomes? = []

Comment: example  var exampleHomes              : MyHomes?    self.exampleHomes.first = "1";   self.selectedHomes.append(self.exampleHomes) this is dont work ?

Comment: this question has been answered.  If you need more help ask another question.

Comment: added here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528700/swift-2-add-class-object-from-another-different-object